Wrapped functions of a Python module raise TypeError
I am currently trying to replace a module in a large code base in a certain condition and to figure out when any function of this module is called, I wrap each function/method in the module with a warning that prints a short message with the stack trace. The implementation of this method is as follows (printing the stack trace was omitted):
def wrap_module_with_warnings(module):
    for fn_name, fn in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if (not (inspect.isfunction(fn) or inspect.ismethod(fn))
                or fn_name.startswith('_')
                or inspect.getmodule(fn) is not module):
            continue

        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs):
            warnings.warn(f"The function {fn_name} was called.")
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        setattr(module, fn_name, wrapped_fn)

Unfortunately, this function doesn't work as I'd expect. My expectation is that it replaces all functions in module with its wrapped variant that just prints a warning and then calls the original function. However, in reality, it throws TypeError: 'module' object is not callable:
/tmp/question/main.py:22: UserWarning: The function random was called.
  warnings.warn(f"The function {fn_name} was called.")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /tmp/question/main.py:31
     29 print(f"Output before wrapping: {mod.f()}")
     30 wrap_module_with_warnings(mod)
---> 31 print(f"Output after wrapping: {mod.f()}")

File /tmp/question/main.py:23, in wrap_module_with_warnings.<locals>.wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     20 @functools.wraps(fn)
     21 def wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs):
     22     warnings.warn(f"The function {fn_name} was called.")
---> 23     return fn(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

To demonstrate my problem, I'm using the following main code:
import mod

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Output before wrapping: {mod.f()}")
    wrap_module_with_warnings(mod)
    print(f"Output after wrapping: {mod.f()}")

and the example module mod.py:
import random


def f() -> int:
    return random.randint(0, 1000)

The error suggests that mod.f is a module. Examining the type of mod.f after calling my wrapper method reveals that it's actually a function:
In [1]: type(mod.f)
Out[1]: function

To examine the original function, I changed the last line of wrap_module_with_warnings to:
setattr(module, fn_name, (fn, wrapped_fn))

and examine mod.f after calling the wrapper doesn't help much either:
In [1]: mod.f[0]
Out[1]: <function mod.f() -> int>

In [2]: mod.f[1]
Out[2]: <function mod.f() -> int>

In [3]: type(mod.f[0])
Out[3]: function

In [4]: type(mod.f[1])
Out[4]: function

In [5]: mod.f[0]()
Out[5]: 785

In [6]: mod.f[1]()
/tmp/AscendSpeed/q/main.py:22: UserWarning: The function random was called.
  warnings.warn(f"The function {fn_name} was called.")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 mod.f[1]()

File /tmp/AscendSpeed/q/main.py:23, in wrap_module_with_warnings.<locals>.wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     20 @functools.wraps(fn)
     21 def wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs):
     22     warnings.warn(f"The function {fn_name} was called.")
---> 23     return fn(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I'm pretty sure that this code should work, fn should be the function mod.f, but why do I get the TypeError then?

The values of fn_name and fn inside of wrapped_fn() are those of the last iteration of your for loop (since the loop has finished before the function ever gets called), rather than the values from the iteration that defined the function.

You're right, thanks! It also prints the warning "The function random was called." Let me try whether it works when I build a constructor function.

Moreover, you are actually assigning the decorator, not the decorated function, I am working on an answer that addresses all the issues.

Ok thanks, when you publish the answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Looks like you got it anyway, my solution is fairly similar to what you got.

Yeah, this was actually my first approach, so I knew immediately after @jasonharper pointed at the issue. But my first approach had another issue (missing the if statement), and then I thought why having the extra wrap_fn, shouldn't it be equivalent to defining the function in the body? Turns out it's not. Thanks anyways. If you want to publish a solution, I'll accept it. Otherwise, I'll close this question tomorrow.

It's fine, essentially your original solution is basically the wrapper - decorators in Python is a function that takes another function as an argument, and a decorated function is the return value of that decorator function (i.e. the wrapper). You only assigned the wrapper, and due to your naming of fn as the for loop variable, it ended up being this confusing mess as that outer fn leaked into what should be the local fn scooped inside the wrapper.

As @jasonharper hinted at in the comments, wrapped_fn doesn't encapsulate fn_name and fn and instead uses those of the last iteration of the loop. The warning
/tmp/AscendSpeed/q/main.py:22: UserWarning: The function random was called.
  warnings.warn(f"The function {fn_name} was called.")

exemplifies that. This problem is easily solved by constructing the wrapper function inside another function:
def wrap_module_with_warnings(module):
    def wrap_fn(f, msg):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs):
            warnings.warn(msg)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped_fn

    for fn_name, fn in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if (not (inspect.isfunction(fn) or inspect.ismethod(fn))
                or fn_name.startswith('_')
                or inspect.getmodule(fn) is not module):
            continue

        wrapped_fn = wrap_fn(fn, f"The function {fn_name} was called.")
        setattr(module, fn_name, wrapped_fn)

